# Renaming file & check-in to Starteam within same commit?

Tags: starteam

I have to rename a file. When renaming the file I have to update another file that refers to it, otherwise I will break the build.

The problem is when trying to do this change in Starteam. The file is renamed on the server immediately when I close the Properties dialog. Until I have checked in the other files the build will be broken. The build won't be broken for very long, but still there is the risk that someone does a checkout in between these two operations.

Is there some way in Starteam to get the rename and the check-in done within the same transaction?

I'm using Starteam Client 2008r2.

Comment: Holy Moses, I did not think that existed anymore! I used to use StarteamPE for a very long time when I started developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to create a transaction, do some work within the GUI, and then commit that transaction.  The docs recommend doing the `rename` within the StarTeam GUI and this must be done by itself so that means that will take place as a single unit of work.

If it was just checking in items, you can do checkin of multiple files at once as a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was hoping there was some way to do it that I had missed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to do this, but it involves branching.

1. Create a new child branch.
2. Make all modifications (renames, edits, etc.)
3. Do a View Compare/Merge.  It should detect the file was Renamed and Modified.
4. Commit your changes.  These will be committed atomically so it should not break the build.

Note that future versions of StarTeam may contain the ability to perform this as a local transaction, which basically means doing the same thing as above but using the VCM tool to merge your View with your Local Working Folder, rather than creating a branch to do it.  This is not currently supported, but to the best of my knowledge they have been working to put the infrastructure for this in place, and it may already be there.  If you haven't checked lately this is something to keep your eyes open for.